# My second for loop is not working in the below code

Tags: python-3.x

```
nums=[0,5,4,12]
n=len(nums)
temp=1
ans=[]
for i in range(n):
    ans.append(temp)
    temp*=nums[i]
temp=1
for i in range(n-1,-1):
    
    ans[i]*=temp
    temp*=nums[i]
    print("yes")
print(ans)
```

> Given an integer array nums, return an array answer such that answer[i] is equal to the product of all the elements of nums except nums[i].
> The product of any prefix or suffix of nums is guaranteed to fit in a 32-bit integer.
> You must write an algorithm that runs in O(n) time and without using the division operation.

This is a solution for this [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/) but my second for loop is not executing, and i don't know why.

Comment: What do you think is in a `range(-1)`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagisorry i didn't change that while pasting directly from debugging, but even with "n" it won't work

Answer (score -1):

Using range like this will result in zero iterations because the "step" parameter is 1. So because it is 1 it will think it should go upwards, but n is already above -1, so it should be like
`range(n, -1, -1)`

also you most probably want

```py
import math

n = [0, 5, 4, 12]
ans = []
for num in n:
    temp = n[:] # create a copy
    temp.remove(num) # remove the number you are on
    ans.append(math.prod(temp)) # use math.prod to multiply the rest together
return ans
```